# Disable Automatic Emails sent to the requestor

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have a workflow set in SP Designer 2013, which starts an approval process with selected people in a SP List in O365. Once a new item is added to the list it sends to the person created this item 2 autogenerated mails:
- Approval has started on (item name)
- Approval has completed on (item name)
It does it as well all the time when item status is changed, so at the end of final approval of the new item there are plenty of useless mails in the requestor mailbox. At the same time mails are sent to selected approvers and this works fine.

Is there a way to disable notifications sent back to the requestor when the request status is changed and send it only when the final approval is received?

[image: workflow example]

Answer (score 1):

As per my test, I don’t have notification email after the status changed.

You can check if you set alert for the list which send alerts to users when existing items are modified via List ribbon->Alert Me->set alert on this list.

Comment: checked. I didnt set it before. Once you open this "Alert me" function your account is automatically entered there

Comment: checked. I didnt set it before. Once you open this "Alert me" function your account is automatically entered there in a "Send Alerts to" field, and you cant delete it and leave this field empty... There is no Alerts in "Manage my alerts" but annoying notifications (Approval has started & Approval has completed) are still sent to me when I add a new item to the list...